# Is the Genius SlimStar 8000 compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, keyboard, mouse

The Genius SlimStar 8000 has caught my eye for use with my new HTPC.  However, I can't get an answer out of Google if it works with Ubuntu (or Linux for that matter).

The reviews over at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Z0KPUG) indicate that it works with Mac, so that is a good sign. Has anyone tried this keyboard successfully?  Failing that, where else can I look?

I really just want basic keyboard functionality, multimedia keys are a nice to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this review about Genius SlimStar 8000:

http://linuxhcl.com/browse/product?id=7769

> Works great, plug and play with Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.